# Gitlab CI/CD Trigger only a single stage in gitlab-ci.yml file on a scheduled pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I want to run a single stage in gitlab from a yml file that contains a lot of stages. I don't want to have to add this to every single stage to avoid running all the stages.

```
except:
    refs:
      - schedules
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add `except` in each job, use `only` instead of except

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced

below there is an example with variables

```
only_with_variable:
  script: ls -la
  only:
    variables:
      - $VAR == "1234"
```

after that if you schedule a pipeline, you have the option to add variables to them.

[image]

in the example, you just need to add the VAR variable with value = 1234

Comment: but the other stages still run. yes when we push commits the pipeline will not trigger the job that says "only schedules" but when we schedule a pipeline to run it will still run the other jobs AND the one that has the only schedules

Comment: use only with a variable. and in your schedule you are able to set this variable!

Comment: can you elaborate on that

Comment: Right but the other jobs defined in the yaml file would still run in the scheduled pipeline. Im trying to run just one specific stage. So if i have a stage test and a stage scheduled_job, test would still run in the scheduled pipeline along with the one the one when the variable matches

Comment: you can use multiple variables and also multiple schedules... just combine them to find the best option

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly defining the `except` tag for each job. You can define it once as an [anchor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors).

```
.job_template: &job_definition
  except:
    refs:
      - schedules

test1:
  <<: *job_definition
  script:
    - test1 project
```

Comment: isn't that kind of the same thing. Im looking for a way that wont require every new stage added in the future to have ot add this to its portion of the yml config

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to run the stage only on a scheduled job

```
build-app:
  stage: build-app
  only:
    - schedules
```